# Looking for a Google script that will perform CTRL+F replace for a string

Tags: regex, string, csv, google-apps-script

I have looked at multiple solutions here for similar tasks, and tried them in different ways.

Essentially, I have a cells with long, somewhat similar strings of text, and I want to isolate specific text markers in order to be able to split on those markers.  The specific string I am looking for is "MHPP" and I want to replace it with "][MHPP " so I can used the split function to split on the "]".

I was able to get it to work by manually Finding and Replacing (CTRL+F and selecting parameters for the replace), but I want to be able to script it because I won't be the one running the script and need to simplify the process for low-information users.

Using =replace(find("MHPP"),7,"][MHPP ") only finds the first instance of the find value, and there may be multiple usages of the term throughout the cell.

Any suggestions?  I suppose there might be a way to write the cell to a string, and replace within the array, but the logic of that process is escaping me at the moment.

I'm not asking for the entire code.  I can activate the sheet, get the range, and work from there, but I just don't know how to write the specific function findAndReplace() that would actually locate all repetitions of the string and replace them all.

I'm also open to importing the .csv into a different format, running a function there, and returning it back out to a .csv, but that hasn't proven to be very fruitful either in my searches.

Thanks for any guidance you can offer to get me on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `replace` [string function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) on every cell in a global iteration of your sheet, do that at array level to keep it fast and simple.
The code itself can be very short and straightforward like this :

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();// get all data
  for(var n=0;n<data.length;n++){
    for(var m=0;m<data[0].length;m++){
      if(typeof(data[n][m])=='string'){ // if it is a string
         data[n][m]=data[n][m].replace(/MHPP/g,'][MHPP');// use the regex replace with /g parameter meaning "globally"
      }
    }
  }
  sh.getDataRange().setValues(data);// update sheet values
}
```

This could be improved to take care of certain situations where the script would be executed twice (or more) to prevent replacement if '][' is already present... I'll let you manage these details.

Comment: Would it be possible to use and all caps regexp, such as ([A-Z]{3,}g), as the match and then prefix whatever all caps value that is found with "]["?  That would probably get me where I need in a more direct way.  Your answer works well, but I see a better way to split my text by lower casing some similar terms, and splitting on what's left in allcaps.

Comment: My answer answers the question, not less, not more... if you want to change / extend the question it's probably a better idea to start a new one don't you think ?

Comment: Yeah, that's fair.  I probably should have asked the other question in the first place, but when I was asking I forgot that I had plotted out a different way to split things up.  I've been chasing this trail for a couple of days and I guess I defaulted back to the original thought process.

I will work from what you provided, and see if I can work it out on my own before I start a new thread that is more specific to my use and less valuable to other users.