# Google Scripts replace function to prefix a regexp in CAPS

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

In GAS, using the .replace(), Is it possible to match any term within a long text string that is at least 5 consecutive ALL CAPS characters (may have 1 space in there) and prefix it with a string, such as ][?  There may be multiple matches within the text string, so I want to insert markers that begin and end a phrase beginning with an ALLCAPS category.

An example of a similar type of text would be this (structurally similar, but with other sensitive data):

"VACATION: Approved by Supervisor - Frequency 1-3 times per year; duration not to exceed 5 days.  SICK LEAVE: Approved by Supervisor - Frequency up to 8 per year, no more than 5 days consecutively without MD excuse.  FMLA FEDERAL: Approved by HR - Frequency as needed, must be approved at least 14 days in advance, or within 24 hours of employee's identified need."

I have learned, through Serge, how to replace globally, which was a big help, but the more I research regexp's, the more confusing it gets.  I tried substituting the all caps regexp for a specific term, but failed.  I think that I could go through and extract all of the all caps regexp's and use them in a replace with multiple values, but it seems that would be a very long way around.

Is it possible, in a couple of lines to make the above text look like this:
"][VACATION: Approved by Supervisor - Frequency 1-3 times per year; duration not to exceed 5 days.  ][SICK LEAVE: Approved by Supervisor - Frequency up to 8 per year, no more than 5 days consecutively without MD excuse.  ][FMLA FEDERAL: Approved by HR - Frequency as needed, must be approved at least 14 days in advance, or within 24 hours of employee's identified need."

My intention is to then split on the ] Which would mean that new cells would start with the all caps term, and end with ].  I have the code to convert the text to an array (there are lots of entries), then use .replace() to find and replace within the array, and to set the values back into the sheet, but I just don't know if there is a way to either prefix (my research says lookback isn't possible in GAS), or to pick up the allcaps value, add the string "][", and put it back.

If this is asking too much, or feels like I haven't included any code, here is the first part that Serge already helped with: [Looking for a Google script that will perform CTRL+F replace for a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249285/looking-for-a-google-script-that-will-perform-ctrlf-replace-for-a-string/21251400?noredirect=1#comment32031941_21251400)

Here is the code, as I used it, combining Serge's previous help and the new recommendation.  I had to fix some case issues with a term before running the all caps because some people can't follow a template, but it works.

```
function insertSplitMarkers(){
      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Freq Iso');
      var data = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();// get all data
      var regexp = /(([A-Z]\s*){5,})/g;
      for(var n=0;n<data.length;n++){
        for(var m=0;m<data[0].length;m++){
          if(typeof(data[n][m])=='string'){ // if it is a string
            data[n][m]=data[n][m].replace(/Interventions/g,'INTERVENTIONS');// use the regex replace with /g parameter meaning "globally"
            data[n][m]=data[n][m].replace(regexp, "][$1");        
          }
        }
      }
      Logger.log(data);
      sh.getRange(2,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
    }
```

Comment: http://regexpal.com/ and https://www.debuggex.com/ should help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this will do what you want although as is, it will also pick out `aoAOEOUE`:

```
var yourString = "VACATION: Approved by Supervisor - Frequency 1-3 times per year; duration not to exceed 5 days. SICK LEAVE: Approved by Supervisor - Frequency up to 8 per year, no more than 5 days consecutively without MD excuse. FMLA FEDERAL: Approved by HR - Frequency as needed, must be approved at least 14 days in advance, or within 24 hours of employee's identified need.";

var regexp = /(([A-Z]\s*){5,})/g;

var newString = yourString.replace(regexp, "][$1");

Logger.log(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3169581 I've adjusted your regex slightly to try to eliminate matching whitespace around the desired phrase and ensure you get the whole desired phrase, it will require a little adjustment in the replace:

```
var regexp = /\b([A-Z\s]{5,})(:)/g
...
data[n][m] = data[n][m].replace(regexp,"][$2$3")
```

Link to regex101 with working matching here: http://regex101.com/r/rD5kS9

HTH

EDIT: for some reason the existing answer wasn't showing up for me when I started this response. Forgive the redundancy.